# Essential to / for

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Should **essential** be followed by **to + base form of the verb** or **for + verb "ing"**? Why?

In my opinion, this requirement is essential **to work / for working** in such an international environment.

Comment: Essential **to** _verb_  (to work) or essential **for** _noun_ (for working).

Comment: Your question seems to suggest that you think that only one of these two options are valid. According to the Cambridge Dictionary, both usages are valid. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/essential

Comment: 'Work' can be a noun too, in which case 'for' is OK.

Comment: @JavaLatte A slip of the tongue, with apologies: **Only one of these two options IS valid.

Comment: @RonaldSole mea culpa

Comment: So, if I well understood what was written, the following sentences are both correct: this requirement is essential to work (verb) in such an international environment. / This requirement is essential for work (noun) in such an international environment.

Comment: While "this requirement is essential for working (verb) in such an international environment. " is wrong. Is everything I wrote correct?

Comment: Can anyone confirm my last comments? Thanks a lot